# Javax validation not working on boot rest controller parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have a Pojo (annotated with Lombok if it makes any difference) and a RestController in a Spring Boot app. The pojo method parameter is annotated with `@Valid` yet there is no validation applied and even if I add a BindingResult second parameter, it never has any error. I'm testing this with Swagger UI, posting a JSON, but I don't see why that would make any differnce... Did I miss something obvious?

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.experimental.Tolerate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;


@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Builder
public class MyPojo extends GenericDocument {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @Tolerate
    public MyPojo() {
    }
}
```

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<MyPojo> createNew(@RequestBody @Valid MyPojo pojo){...
    }
}
```

**Solution**
Adding this dependency was enough:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

It is strange that adding `javax.validation:validation-api` and `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator` was not enough despite the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-jsr303)

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but the usage of ```@Valid``` that I have seen until now were like ```@Valid @RequestBody MyPojo pojo``` and not ```@RequestBody @Valid MyPojo pojo```. Can you try this once?

Comment: If you apply @Damodar Hegde advice then I have the same configurations and it works for me. I would just remove the lombok annotations and especially this experimental. Then in my case it works very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-jsr303), which is not entirely clear, you need to have a JSR-303 validation provider such as [Hibernate Validator](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.hibernate.validator%20AND%20a:hibernate-validator&core=gav) (docs [here](https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/)) on your classpath so Spring can detect and use it.

It also seems in some cases you may need the Spring Boot Starter Validation [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation) (spring-boot-starter-validation) on your classpath as well. I would suggest trying that to see if it helps. (Strangely, though, I don't see that detailed in the Spring docs - just briefly mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/).)

Or you could maybe implement the Validator interface as per [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator), but not sure.

Comment: Well put, the documentation is unclear. It worked using only `spring-boot-starter-validation`

Answer (score 2):

You should try adding Spring’s `@Validated` annotation to the controller at class level to tell Spring to evaluate the constraint annotations on method parameters.

Example:

```java
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<MyPojo> createNew(@RequestBody @Valid MyPojo pojo){...
    }
}
```

This `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` annotation can be applied at both class level and method or parameter level.